# c# making a short date ends up adding one day

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, localtime

I am trying to make a short date, but in the result I get one day more. With date like "2014-01-03 00:00:00" its okay, but it fails when time is "23:59:59".

EntryDate= "2014-01-03 23:59:59"

but getting result = "2014-01-04"

```
  try
        {
            DateTime exact = DateTime.ParseExact(EntryDate, "yyyyMMdd", (IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            mventryAttrib.Value = (exact.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime exact = DateTime.ParseExact(EntryDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", (IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                mventryAttrib.Value = (exact.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            }
            catch
            {
            }
```

Comment: what about adding .Date at the end of the call to ParseExact (to remove the time component). Also, would the ToLocalTime() not be messing with the date anyway depending on the originating timezone?

Comment: This is due to `ToLocalTime`. If you're in a timezone that adds hours, then this will bump it into 2014-01-04.

Comment: Why are you converting to local time if you don't care about the time?  That will adjust the time which would make it the next day your time zone is ahead.  If you just convert `exact` to string then it will give you the right date.

Comment: Most probably the issue is that you are converting the parsed time to your local time. For instance if you are located at UTC+2 time zone and the exact time is Utc, the converted date time would be "2014-1-4 1:59:59", hence mventryAttrib.Value would be "2015-01-04".

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use explicit casting to `IFormatProvider` interface since `CultureInfo` class _already_ implements it. Just `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to `ParseExact` returns a `DateTime` with a `Kind` property value of `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.

This, when coupled with a call to `.ToLocalTime()` when you're in a timezone that has a positive offset from UTC, will bump the `DateTime` value forward by that many hours and return a `DateTime` value with a `Kind` property value of `DateTimeKind.Local`.

Here is a short program that will demonstrate:

```
var exact = DateTime.ParseExact("2014-01-03 23:59:59", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine($"{exact} - {exact.Kind}");

var local = exact.ToLocalTime();
Console.WriteLine($"{local} - {local.Kind}");

Console.WriteLine(TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(exact));
```

Output (on my machine):

```
03.01.2014 23.59.59 - Unspecified
04.01.2014 00.59.59 - Local
01:00.00
```

If you intended the parsed `DateTime` value to be local from the outset you should make a new value that is specifically local, with the same values:

```
exact = new DateTime(exact.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Local);
```

Be aware though that this may have unforseen consequences when dealing with timezone boundaries. I would urge you to find a better library than the built in DateTime types, such as [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/).

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you are setting the time in exact as a UTC time and then converting this to a local time.  This conversion is adding a number of hours to the time and consequently moving the date along.

Try exact.ToUniversalTime() and you should get the date you set.

Answer (score 0):

I think this site could help you to solve the problem.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx